# Python variables in IF statement

Tags: python, variables, fabric

I've looked for a solution but none of the ones I've seen are the same as my issue. I'm using fabric with a run command to run hostname -i remotely. So here is what I have:

```
ip = run("hostname -i")
if %s in run("nodetool -h localhost ring | awk '{ print $1}' | grep `hostname -i`") % ip:
        print(green("The host is in the ring"))
```

Im just trying to check if the ip address of the current server is showing up when running the nodetool command. Not how to accomplish this. I'm new to python.

So i tried to assign an "ip" to the variable and had an error which spurred the question:

```
>>> ip = 10.0.0.1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ip = 10.0.0.1
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

EDIT:

```
I tried a few things and this seems to work:

>>> ip = local("hostname -i")
[localhost] local: hostname -i
10.88.17.59
>>> if ip > 1:
...     print "yes"
... else:
...     print "no"
... 
yes
>>> if ip in local("hostname -i"):
...     print "yes"
... else:
...     print "no"
... 
[localhost] local: hostname -i
10.88.17.59
yes
```

Comment: Does the `run()` function return the output from the command?  And are you looking for the literal string '%s' in this output?

Comment: Thanks for you response. I disable verbose output. run() just "runs" the command remotely on a defined list of servers. I was guessing on the string part. I've thought of doing a for loop but each server will have a different IP to query for. So, im stuck.

Comment: Just do `if ip in run(...)`. % is for string formatting, not substitution everywhere.

Comment: Thanks wooble. I had that originally but am not able to test. I'll have to create a test environment to see what happens. EDIT: Added info to the original question.

Comment: Among the other issues that people are pointing out, your IP needs to be a string, e.g. `ip = '10.0.0.1'`

Answer (score -1):

I tried a few things and this seems to work:

```
>>> ip = local("hostname -i")
[localhost] local: hostname -i
10.1.2.3
>>> if ip > 1:
...     print "yes"
... else:
...     print "no"
... 
yes
>>> if ip in local("hostname -i"):
...     print "yes"
... else:
...     print "no"
... 
[localhost] local: hostname -i
10.1.2.3
yes
```

Comment: At least tell me why you would downvote. I thought I was being helpful by posting my discovery.